# launch process foreground on boot

Tags: debian, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I know how to launch programs in the background with `cron` on boot or at certain intervals, but in this case, I want to launch a python script in the foreground, automatically when the computer starts, so I immediately start seeing its output in the screen.

Is that possible without my intervention?

Comment: Are you running systemd or sysv init?

Comment: systemd is present in my system (but I never used it)

Comment: Which "screen"....the console?

Comment: @mdpc yes, the console

Comment: I have only done this with sysvinit personally (where you edit /etc/inittab), haven't yet done it with systemd. But this should get you started: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html ... basically, the idea is you start your program instead of getty. No time to try it out, or I'd post an actual answer. (Everyone else please feel free to post a real answer).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your distribution, you can place the script in a run level (that is executed **after** your user is logged). In contrast to cron, it will be executed interactively!

You have to check what are your run level meaning (because you might changed it from the default).

The default run levels for Debian & Ubuntu are:

- 0 System Halt
- 1 Single user
- 2 Full multi-user mode (Default)
- 3-5 Same as 2
- 6 System Reboot

place the script here /etc/rcX.d
just place the file in the right run level and it will be executed after the machine starts up